# Check for duplicated entry doesn't work

Tags: c, boolean, duplicates

I'm currently creating C console program. In my program, I can add and edit my records, I decided to check for duplicated entry for my every id in my record. I'm using boolean to check the duplicated entry. The problem I faced now is my record having the same data as the previous entry.

```
typedef struct People
{
char code[100],name[100];
int age,height,weight;
}People;

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

void add(char* code, char* name, int* age, int* height, int* weight)
{
bool is_matched = false;
char searchCode[100];
printf("Enter code name age height weight:");
scanf("%s %s %d %d %d",code, name, &age, &height, &weight);

/* Check for Duplicated Entry Below*/
}

int main()
{
People person;
add(&person.code,&person.name,&person,age,&person.height,&person.weight);
return 0;
}
```

Check for Duplicated entry

```
while(fscanf(fp1,"%s %s %d %d %d",searchCode, name, &age, &height, &weight) == 5)
{
    if(strcmp(searchCode,code) == 0)
    {
            printf("Model Code already exist in the records.\n");
            printf("Please try different model code.\n");
            is_matched = true;
            break;
    }

}

 if(!is_matched){
     fprintf(fp1,"%s %s %d %d %d\n",code,name,age,height,weight);
}
```

Comment: are you sure this program doesn't crash when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading your stuff incorrectly!

when you say:

```
 scanf("%d", second_parameter);
```

this second parameter is supposed to be **an address**, that is why we use the operator &, to extract the address of the variable it is applied to.

Your function header is:

```
 void add(char* code, char* name, int* age, int* height, int* weight)
```

**ALL** parameters are pointers and you are getting the address of that pointer (not the address of the variable it points to) when you call scanf, I would reccomend you to:

1 - change your scanf statement to:

```
  scanf("%s %s %d %d %d",code, name, age, height, weight);
```

2 - Change your function call to:

```
 add(person.code,person.name,&person,age,&person.height,&person.weight);
```

Change your fscanf too... then run it again and see if it works